# Why should privileges be taken away when I lose points by giving bounties?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, privileges

Why should privileges be taken away when I lose points by giving bounties?
Giving bounties for improving answers help the site, but now I am nearly going to be kicked off of the site for trying to improve its contents.

Comment: I was forced to tag this as a bug??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by-design. (For some of the reasons, please see [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11930/1438).) When you lose reputation for any reason, you risk losing privileges. Bounties aren't special in this regard.

It might be worthwhile to add a warning when offering a bounty that will reduce your reputation below the level needed to maintain your current set of privileges.

Comment: I remember that warning now... I dont like it but I am sure biased about it at this time :) and would like it to be different.